# How can i put UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert on the right?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to know how can i put UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert on the right in UITableView like in this picture:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can create a `UIButton` with the type `UIButtonTypeContactAdd` and add it as an accessory view:

```
UIButton *accessory = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
[cell setAccessoryView:accessory];
```

The icon is blue, though; if you want it to be green like `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert`, you have to make a button with a custom image instead of using `UIButtonTypeContactAdd`.